# Java: ArrayStoreException

Tags: java, arrays, generics, exception

I would like fill an external array with the elements of my ArrayQueue via `E[] toArray(E[] a)` , but somehow it throws `ArrayStoreException` at the first `System.arraycopy` method. I would like to know how to solve this issue, and even more important for me to know **why this exception is thrown.**

Here's my code:

```
public E[] toArray(E[] a)
{
    if(a.length != size) 
        a=(E[])Array.newInstance(a.getClass(), size); 
    if(head<tail)
        System.arraycopy(elementData, head, a, 0, tail-head); // ArrayStoreException
    else
    {
        System.arraycopy(elementData, head, a, 0, capacity-head);
        System.arraycopy(elementData, 0, a, capacity-head, tail);
    }
    return a;           
}
```

This is the external method:

```
String[] words = q.toArray(new String[2]);
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Could you show a [mcve] demonstrating the issue? (Is this in a generic type? I assume so...) The simpler you make it for us to reproduce, the easier it is to help you.

Comment: (Actually, I suspect I know the problem - just checking now...)

Comment: Sorry, but i do not have a clue what extra information should i provide to solve this. My ArrayQueue is generic, it has a field `E[] elementData` which contains the elements. The underlying type of `elementData` is `Object`, and it is casted in the consturctor to `(E[])`

Comment: The extra information would be a short but complete example - something we could copy, paste, compile and run to see the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the exception doesn't *actually* happen on the line you've indicated, but later, in `System.arraycopy`.

The problem is that your call to `Array.newInstance` passes in the *array type*, when you only want to pass in the *element type*. In other words, you're saying "Give me a new array with an element type `String[]`" where you really want to say "Give me a new array with an element type `String`".

To do this, just use `getClass().getComponentType()`. Demo which is a simpler but complete example of the problem, if you remove `getComponentType()`:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] original = new String[] { "x" };
        String[] x =  Test.<String>toArray(original);
    }

    public static <E> E[] toArray(E[] a) {
        E[] copy = (E[]) Array.newInstance(a.getClass().getComponentType(), a.length + 1);
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, copy, 0, a.length);
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`a.getClass()` will not return `E`, it will return an *array of E* (since a is an array). this is why you're having trouble with the assignment